# Continue program when no key is pressed

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to make Snake in assembly as an exercise. Most of it works alright, if not great, but I'm having trouble continuing the loop when no key has been pressed. The problem is, that the program waits for me to press a key even when I do not want to change the direction of the snake.

```
        mov ah, 00h
        int 16h
        jmp checkKeys

checkKeys:
        cmp ah, 75
        je leftArrowKey
        cmp ah, 72
        je upArrowKey
        cmp ah, 77
        je rightArrowKey
        cmp ah, 80
        je downArrowKey
```

How do I make sure to loop the program when no keys are being pressed?

Comment: Use [this](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm). Remeber to consume the key, if present, the usual way.

Comment: I've tried to use int 16 with 01h, but all it does now is move in the starting direction without stopping. No keyboard input works.

Comment: Int16h/AH=01h is not a drop-in replacement for Int16h/AH=00h. The page linked should have all the information. Particularly, test the Zero Flag and if set, skip the code you already have. There should be examples here on SO on using Int16h/AH=01h

Comment: Thanks a lot! I set it up with the zero flag but it didn't work. Just noticed I was just skipping to the wrong label.